# Create .NET Core WebApi with older SDK version

Tags: .net-core

I have .NET Core with both 2.1 and 2.2 SDKs installed. When run `dotnet new webapi` it uses version 2.2 but I need 2.1. I tried with `dotnet new webapi --sdk-version=2.1` but I'm getting an error:

```
Invalid input switch:
  --sdk-version=2.1
```

What is the correct flag to use?

Comment: `dotnet new globaljson --sdk-version 2.1.500` and then `dotnet new webapi`.

Comment: Thank you, this worked, but it had to be 2.1.2 for me. Also I had to delete the globaljson first because all `dotnet` commands stopped working when I created it with a wrong sdk version by mistake.